# Why it's possible to invoke a function declared later in C?

Tags: c

I have this little code to demonstrate it:

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main() {
    int a = testfunc();  // declared later
    printf("%d", a);
    return 0;
}

int testfunc() {
    return 1;
}
```

It compiles with no error, and a outputs `1` as expected.

See in action: http://ideone.com/WRF94E

Why there is no error? Is it part of the spec of C or a compiler related thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function testfunc() is implicitly declared. The compiler cannot do any signature checks so you might get a runtime error in case you fail to invoke it corectly.

This is part of the C specification. But the recommendation in the C specification is to declare all the functions you plan to implement and use, at the beginning of the current file or in a header file.

Comment: To clarify, "runtime error" means "something might go wrong, who knows what?"  Maybe your program will crash, maybe it will give you the wrong answer, maybe it will download pictures of cats.

Comment: @xiaoyi. Try calling testfunc(1). You will get a runtime error.

Answer (score 2):

Because, by default the compiler considers the undeclared functions as

```
int function_name ();
```

Internally, an undeclared function is considered with return type as int and accepts any number of arguments.It matches with your actual function also. so no issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is compiler dependant. Some compilers will emit an error, others - a warning, while others - nothing. The compiler duty is only to check that you use the function with the correct arguments. If you don't declare it, then the compiler can't check and warn you for misuse of the function, but it can generate the code for calling the function.
The linker duty, on the other hand, is to see that the function is implemented and put its address in the call generated previously by the compiler. Since your function is implemented, the linker works fine.

Since your compiler doesn't check you, you can try calling your function with arguments. The call might work but might also make your program crash.

Comment: What compiler will emit an error?  Such a compiler would not be C89 compliant, at least.

Comment: Actually, I'm quite sure that this is allowed by the standard (although it's not recommended, implicit declarations come from the ancient times of C)  so there's no way that a compliant compiler can give an error on this.

Comment: I think the stardard doesn't require this, but the standard is old, and compilers are new. And many C compilers are much stricter than the standard. GCC withe -Wall will even pick into your printf to warn you against unmatched arguments, which is not even "compiling". I see more and compiler that warn and even error about lack of functions declarations.

Answer (score 1):

```
int a = testfunc();

int testfunc() {
    return 1;
}
```

You are not getting any error because in C default function signature is the same.

If you want the compiler to tell you see the demo below:

call like this without forward declaration and see compiler will give you error.

```
int a=testfunc(5.4);

int testfunc(float f)
{
 return 1;
}
```

NOTE : The best practice in C is to give `forward declaration` of functions which you are going to use it in program.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler doesn't need to see a function definition to call it, it only needs a *prototype* to check the arguments, if there isn't any, the compiler will assume the function returns `int` and that you know what you're doing. However, when linking if the linker can not resolve a symbol only then you will get an error.

Answer (score 1):

In ANSI C, you do not have to declare a function prototype; however, it is a best practice to use them. 
If you do not have a prototype, and you call a function, the compiler will infer a prototype from the parameters you pass to the function.The compiler assumes that it has an int return type. If you declare the function later in the same compilation unit with a different return type, you'll get a compile error.